# How to set a max number of checked boxes

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, material-ui

I have a list of option with a corresponding checkbox (Material-UI)
And I'm trying to figure out how I Can set a max number on checked boxes
(for instance, I would only want the user to be able to click three and then disable the rest)
Do I do this in the state?

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: 260,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
});

class CheckboxList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checked: [0],
  };

  handleToggle = value => () => {
    const { checked } = this.state;
    const currentIndex = checked.indexOf(value);
    const newChecked = [...checked];

    if (currentIndex === -1) {
      newChecked.push(value);
    } else {
      newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1);
    }

    this.setState({
      checked: newChecked,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const toppings = ['Chicken', 'Pineapple', 'Corn', 'Olives (green)', 'Red union', 'Spinach', 'Cherry tomatoes']
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <List>
          {toppings.map(value => (
            <ListItem
              key={value}
              role={undefined}
              dense
              button
              onClick={this.handleToggle(value)}
              className={classes.listItem}
            >
              <Checkbox
                checked={this.state.checked.indexOf(value) !== -1}
                tabIndex={-1}
                disableRipple
              />
              <ListItemText primary={`NewAge ${value}`} />

            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

CheckboxList.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CheckboxList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
shouldDisableCheckbox = value => {
   // either from props: const { maxAllowed } = this.props
   // or from state: const { maxAllowed } = this.state
   // or just a constant:
   const maxAllowed = 3
   const { checked } = this.state
   return checked.length >= maxAllowed && checked.indexOf(value) === -1
}
```

then use it in your checkbox:

```
<Checkbox
   checked={this.state.checked.indexOf(value) !== -1}
   tabIndex={-1}
   disabled={this.shouldDisableCheckbox(value)}
   disableRipple
/>
```

things like **maxAllowed** shouldn't be in the state but more like in a constant or passed in as a prop (with a default value if nothing is provided), as **maxAllowed** is a configuration value thus it's place is not in the state. State usually should hold stuff that change.

Also, as with all UI validation, backend/api should not trust this validation too, as it's way too easy to trick and remove.

Comment: Thank You!
this works Perfectly.

Had to put the 
disabled={this.shouldDisableCheckbox(value)}
In the ListItem component, then it disabled the rest.

Comment: You're welcome, and yeah, that depends on your custom components.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the `Checkbox` is coming from, but you should be able to give it the property of `disabled`, which, in react, can be given a boolean value. `disabled={true}`. So you could do something like `disabled={this.state.checked.length >= 3 && [some logic to make sure you're not disabling one that is active]}`. Better form would be to put this in a function and link to it, since it has much logic attached. You shouldn't need to add anything to your state.